# Motto -- All Debts Will be Paid

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

Looking for use of this in a motto, like below a family coat of arms. No matter what, we will pay our debts to those we owe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, and there are a million possible answers to it, but I will list fewer than that here, and others will also, I hope, add a few more possibilities.

- "Debita solventur omnia" is a straightforward sentence which means simply that all debts will be paid. The word order can be re-arranged to whatever you like with no change in meaning and only slight change in emphasis.
- You can replace "solventur" above with "persolventur" to mean paid in full, a more emphatic expression.
- You could change the indicative "solventur" (will be paid) to a jussive "solvantur" (let them be paid!). Again, you can put the prefix "per-" in front of "solvantur" to emphasize this.
- If you want something even more legal sounding, official, and old fashioned, you can replace "solvantur" with "solvuntor".

I could go on, but I've probably said more than enough!

Answer (score 1):

Matthew 18:28 has a pithy way of expressing this:

> Redde quod debes.

Literally: "Give back what you owe."

This comes with a major caveat, however: it's in the context of the [Parable of the Unforgiving Servant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Unforgiving_Servant), and is uttered by the petty servant. The full story can be found in Matthew 18:23-35, and the portrait isn't very flattering:

> . . . Egressus autem servus ille invenit unum de conservis suis, qui debebat ei centum denarios: et tenens suffocavit eum, dicens: **Redde quod debes.** Et procidens conservus ejus, rogabat eum, dicens: Patientiam habe in me, et omnia reddam tibi. Ille autem noluit: sed abiit, et misit eum in carcerem donec redderet debitum. . . .

Comment: That's a pretty neat observation. You could personalize it to "Reddo quod debeo" (I pay what I owe) or "reddimus quod debemus" (we pay what we owe).